# Proving continuity in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let f:D(subset of R^2)->R be a function and (a,b) belongs to D.If f(x,y) is continuous at (a,b) then show that functions f(x,b) and f(a,y) are continuous at x=a and at y=b respectively.

Can we solve it like this?

Since f(x,y) is continuous at (a,b) so for given epsilon e>0 there exists delta d>0 such that
|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|<e whenever |x-a|<d and |y-b|<d

Since |f(x,b)-f(a,b)|<=|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|<e wheneverr |x-a|<delta  thus f(x,b) is continous at x=a.

Similarly f(a,y) continuity can be proven at y=b.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

That is almost correct, but not totally. What you should say is that, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\delta\implies|f(x,y)-f(a,b)|<\varepsilon.$$Then, if $|x-a|<\delta$, you have$$\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(b-b)^2}=|x-a|<\delta$$and therefore $|f(x,b)-f(a,b)|<\varepsilon$.